# Proxy youtube iframe through my server

Tags: iframe, youtube, proxy, youtube-api

I want to show youtube videos on my website. It is possible with iframe and i only need to put it on my webpage like this.

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" 
src="//www.youtube.com/embed/wtLJPvx7-ys?rel=0"
frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Everything is good except more than 99% of my customers come from Iran and youtube is blocked in Iran by government. So getting data directly form youtube servers is not an option for me.

My app is hugly depends on youtube and I'm looking for a way to proxy video data through my server. I'm already doing it with youtube data APIs to get json data (search results, etc.) but for palying videos i don't know what to do since it's iframe and i don't have much of a control over it.

any suggestions?

Comment: @AlirezeA.Ahmed any updates?

Comment: No, I didn't find a solution for this. It's probably possible to download and host the videos on our own servers but that's most likely is illegal!

Answer (score 1):

You can use proxy through nginx server for that. For more information you can refer http://code.google.com/p/youtube-cache/